# .htaccess Subdomain Rewrite (not like other questions!)

Tags: .htaccess

I wish to rewrite admin.example.com/test/ to admin.example.com/index.php?site=test.

I have done ample research and have yet to be able to do so. Regex is not my thing, anyone have suggestions?

(in this particular example, only 'test' is a variable (i.e. 'admin' is constant'))

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to do so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?site=$1
```

And if you want to restrict that rule to *admin.example.com*, add this condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.example.com
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?site=$1
```